# How to set fewer than 32 bpp for SDL window?

Tags: c, sdl, color-depth

I've been trying to write a program that uses SDL for drawing, but I've been unable to find any way to set 15-bits per pixel (2 bytes per pixel) rather than the 4-byte RGBA that it sets by default. I get a segfault whenever I try to blit from a 15bpp back buffer (an array of shorts) to the screen surface. The window was defined as

```
window = SDL_CreateWindow("UFC32 Emulator v0.2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

Meanwhile, I tried to do a copy this way.

```
screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
SDL_BlitSurface(backBuffer, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);
```

What I'm looking for is a substitute for my window creation code where I can set the color depth.

Comment: At least one platform that SDL supports (X11) can't switch color depth on the fly. So I suppose there's no API to choose color depth with SDL. If you need to posterize the image, you'll have to round subpixel values in a shader.

Comment: @Ruslan I see, though that is a shame since I'm on Windows and not X11, and I'm mainly aiming to set the window color depth once and forget. My solution is similar to yours, but rather than writing a shader, I just call a convert() function every frame to do a bitmask and bitshift to convert between the two.